# Extract word that doesn't exist in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

My end goal is to print a list of items that exist in one file and do not exist in the other.

I have tried changing each file to a list and comparing the lists, but it still prints out all items in first list. 
(also open to other methods than comparing lists)

File1 fruits

```
apples
bananas
blueberries
watermelons
oranges
kiwis
```

File2 eats

```
I like to eat apples
I like to eat bananas
I like to eat oranges
I like to eat watermelon
```

sample script

```py
fruitList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("fruits")]       

eatsList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("eats")]         


for item in fruitList:
    if item not in eatsList:
       print(item)
```

This is just a small sample I have tried to create to get the end goal

I'd like to compare the fruits file to the eats file and find just the fruits that do not exist in the eats file

so end should be a file that just contains
blueberries
kiwis

I am open to other methods than comparing 2 lists together, the final files to compare will have 7-12 thousand lines to compare to each other

Comment: All you need to do is split your "I like to eat" sentences and take the last word. Everything else you've done will work then. Instead of `eatsList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line...` do `eatsList = [line.rstrip('\n').split()[-1] for line...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing lines between the two files, instead of comparing words. You can make lists of words like this, and then your code should work:

```
with open("fruits") as f:
    fruitList = [
        word 
        for line in f       
        for word in line.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
    ]
with open("eats") as f:
    eatsList = [
        word 
        for line in f       
        for word in line.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
    ]         

for item in fruitList:
    if item not in eatsList:
       print(item)
```

Or you can make it more efficient by using sets and set operations:

```
with open("fruits") as f:
    fruits_set = {
        word 
        for line in f       
        for word in line.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
    }
with open("eats") as f:
    eats_set = {
        word 
        for line in f       
        for word in line.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
    }

missing_items = fruits_set - eats_set
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is going to do the trick so far, or at least give me a point to jump from.

Answer (score 0):

Treat them as sets and assume that fruits are the last word:

```
fruitSet = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("fruits")}
eatsSet = {line.rstrip('\n').split()[-1] for line in open("eats")}
print(fruitSet - eatsSet)
```

Output:

```
{'watermelons', 'blueberries', 'kiwis'}
```

Note that this does not handle singular/plural. To handle that in the general case you may need to use a library like [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for matches in the elements of `eatsList`, not `eatsList` itself. `any`/`all` can help you with that:

```
for item in fruitList:
    if not any(item in s for s in eatsList):
       print(item)
```

Equivalent:

```
for item in fruitList:
    if all(item not in s for s in eatsList):
       print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, roughly speaking, the `list` you get from the first file contains *words* (`'apples'`, `'bananas'`, while the one you get from the second file contains *sentences* (`'I like to eat apples'`, `'I like to eat bananas'`).

Accordingly, you will need to perform extra processing on the second file to change it to the same form as the first:

```
from itertools import chain

with open('eats') as f:
    eats_words = set(chain.from_iterable(row.strip().split() for row in f))

with open('fruits') as f:
    fruits_words = {word.strip() for word in f if word.strip() not in eats_words}
```